# Visual Studio File Cannot be found error

Tags: c#

I recently restructured some data in a game I'm working on by making the folder structure more logical. I went through my code and made the updates for the new structure. However, everytime I try and build, I'm getting this error:

Error 159 File 'Images\Defense Boost Large.png' cannot be found.

The problem is, I can't find where this file is actually referenced. I did a solution wide search and I can't find it anywhere. I looked in resources, settings, config etc. but I can't find a reference to it so I'm at a loss.

Anyone know what might be wrong? If it matters, this is Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows 7(x64) and the language is C#

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .csproj files are XML so, when in doubt, grep the files.

Open a command prompt, change to the top-level directory containing your solution, and run this:

```
findstr /is /c:"Images\Defense Boost Large.png" *.csproj
```

That should help you track it down.

Comment: findstr is a windows command, so should work fine on windows.